# Compute the Sum of Columns in SPSS

Tags: spss

I have a lot of columns in SPSS and for a calculation, I need to get the sum of each and every one of them. Is there a way to do this in SPSS?

An example of what I mean is shown below:

```
age      gender     question 1     question 2
-------------------------------------------------
25         m            2              3
19         f            4              2    
20         f            3              4
                     -------        -------
                    need sum       need sum
```

Comment: just run the DESCRIPTIVE  frequency and you will get Sum as your result

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you just need an ouput table with the results then see the [`DESCRIPTIVES`](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSLVMB_21.0.0/com.ibm.spss.statistics.help/syn_descriptives.htm) command.

Alternatively, if you need the results in an output dataset for further processing then see the [`AGGREGATE`](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSLVMB_21.0.0/com.ibm.spss.statistics.help/syn_aggregate.htm) command.

Comment: `FREQUENCY` can output sums of variables as well.

Answer (score 0):

use:    **Analyse > Reports > Summaries in Columns** and add  your columns